# Magento 2 CMS Block: Is it possible to use another directive within translate directive?

Tags: magento2, cms-block, template-directive

For example I have a CMS block with a text I want to translate but I have a link inside this text that uses the `{{store url=""}}` directive.

In my cms block:

```
{{trans "Foo <a href="{{store url=""}}">bar</a>"}}
```

In my translation:

```
"Foo <a href=""{{store url=""""}}"">bar</a>","My <a href=""{{store url=""""}}"">translation</a>"
```

It results in: `Foo <a href="{{store url="">bar"}}`

Is it just not possible or do I have any other mistake?

Comment: I think the directives are done via preg_match, so I think it is not possible.

Comment: That's true didn't think about it. I think it's handled here: `\Magento\Framework\Filter\Template`